# Combine NestJS and Bull for standalone application

Tags: node.js, nestjs, bullmq

I would like to know if there is some trick to combine NestJS and Bull for a standalone application.

My use case : I run a batch every month that process a large csv file (6Gb, million of lines). It takes so long for processing each lines. I searched about NodeJs worker, but the best idea would be Bull (which are easy to do with NestJs). However, it is a standalone application (batch), so if I create a queue with parallel tasks, the program will exist before all items in queue were processed.

Do you have an idea to run tasks in parallel but wait for all tasks processed ?

Thank you